# Kicad: Connect power to bidirectional pin

Tags: kicad

My design uses an IC with bi-directional I/O pins. For various reasons I need to connect GND to one of these pins, but Kicad warns about this:

> ErrType(4): Conflict problems between pins. Severity: warning
>   * Pin 1 (Power output) of component #FLG032 is connected to
>   * Pin 4 (Bidirectional) of component U1

I can override this warning globally in the ERC settings, but is there a better way to disable the warning for just this one pin?

Comment: Personally, I just note the issue, and once verified correct, ignore it in the ERC log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **know** that your I/O pin won't be outputting (that is why the warning is defaulted for I/O), then you can use a Net Tie:

[image: Net-Tie]

The Footprint looks like this:

[image: Net Tie footprint]